# How is an instance and a schema impact the memory usage in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, memory

I'm fresh for PostgreSQL. I'm investigating the difference of DB instance and DB schema from the memory usage perspective.

I understand new instance is the physical separation and new schema is the logic separation. I also looked into some documents of the memory usage for PostgreSQL. But all of them focus on the memory usage of query or something like that.

I'm wondering whether it introduce any further memory occupation or work load for a new instance or a new schema? Does new instance occupy more memory than new schema?

Comment: Yes, Because the new instance has to run many process in background which is shared across the schema.

Comment: Most of all, it has its own shared memory cache. But I recommend making that decision based on usability, not on resources.

Comment: I agree with Laurenz: the real question is: what are you trying to achieve with that? What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: My production is a memory sensitive environment. So I don't want to introduce more memory usage into the system even tens of MB. The problem is that in such a critical environment the architect designed a micro-service system. So now, I'm investigating how to separate the data: by instance or by schema? I believe the Schema is a concept for PostgreSQL only. I don't think there is a corresponding concept in MySQL or Oracle right?